# Qt How to know when a checkbox is selected when created dynamically?

Tags: qt, checkbox, dynamic

I am trying to dynamically create a checkbox for each restaurant in a vector. I was able to dynamically create checkboxes, but I would then like to know which ones were selected. Here is my code:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < restaurantList.size(); i++)
{
   QCheckBox *thisCheckBox = new QCheckBox(restaurantList.at(i).GetName());
   CTui->verticalLayout->addWidget(thisCheckBox);
}
```

I currently have 5 restaurants filled in the vector, and as of now I have it look something like this:

() McDonalds

() Papa John's

() Burger King

() Dominos

() Taco Bell

When they click an "OK" button, I would like to know which ones were selected. They are all called thisCheckBox, so I don't know how to get each specific one. How can I do this? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You could store pointers to these objects in a container. I'd try something like `QVector< QCheckBox* >` or maybe `QHash< QString, QCheckBox* >` depending on the use case.

Comment: @hyde That could work, I will let you know! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to achieve your goal is to amend the creation loop like this:

```
// Add this to your widget's class declaration:
std::vector<QCheckBox*> checkBoxes;
```

then

```
for (auto& r : restaurantList) {
    auto cb = new QCheckBox(r.GetName());
    checkBoxes.push_back(cb);
    connect(cb, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, &YourWidget::onCheckBoxClicked);
    CTui->verticalLayout->addWidget(cb);
}
```

then add a handler function to `YourWidget` (whatever it may be) like this:

```
void YourWidget::onCheckBoxClicked(int state)
{
    // If you wanted to work with the specific checkbox clicked:
    // Use QObject::sender() to retrieve a pointer to the QCheckBox,
    // and cast it from QObject* to QCheckBox*:
    // auto cb = qobject_cast<QCheckBox*>(sender());

    // Otherwise, if you don't care which, and want to work with them all:
    // Loop over all your checkboxes, doing whatever you want:
    for (auto cb : checkBoxes) {
        qDebug() << "The checkbox with text" << cb->text() << "has state" << state;
    }
}
```

Add this to the slots in the declaration of `YourWidget`.

Comment: Interesting, so to be clear on whats going on: 1. create a checkbox vector 2. add the checkbox to the vector 3. connect? what does that do?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html If you want to use Qt, please read that carefully, and return to it often. Without connecting the `QCheckBox::stateChanged` signal to a slot, nothing happens when the user clicks the checkbox. For each checkbox we create, we are connecting this signal to our handler, in this case a member function of the same class called `onCheckBoxClicked`. Because we have saved pointers to each checkbox, we can then iterate through them.